# Azure AD B2C with MSAL change redirect url on success

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js, msal-react

I have a React app which uses MSAL msal-react v1.3.1. I am using `loginRedirect` method to redirect a predefined user flow configured in Azure B2C for password reset. The current behaviour is that when the password reset is complete it redirects back to the page that first invoked the redirect to AD B2C once it has completed successfully.

Is there a way to change the redirect url when the flow has completed to something like below?

```
instance.loginRedirect({
    authority: `${config.authentication.authority}/${config.authentication.flow.register}`,
    redirectUri: window.location.href + '?success=true'
});
```

I have tried to set the `redirectUri` and `postLoginRedirectUri` which don't appear to change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a restriction on the `redirectUrl` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

The redirect url must be registered with the application and cannot contain wildcards or query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do in this situation was set the **navigateToLoginRequestUrl** to false where you set up your msal. Example of someone's code with the **navigateToLoginRequestUrl** option: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/3818

Then maybe you could use the **state** option to pass any information you want to the return URL instead of a query parameter on returnURL. But I don't quite see the point here.

```
instance.loginRedirect({
        authority: `${config.authentication.authority}/${config.authentication.flow.register}`,
        redirectUri: window.location.href,
        state: 'success'
});
```